# Apple has just unlisted all its 2010-2011 videos: what now for the broken links?

Tags: discussion, broken-link

A month ago (June 8-9 2019), I started fixing some broken links to old 2010 and 2011 WWDC videos, as I discovered that they had been moved to https://developer.apple.com/videos/archive/.

Today, I'm discovering that the above address is redirecting to https://developer.apple.com/videos/all-videos/, and the videos from WWDC 2010 and WWDC 2011 are nowhere to be found. (for reference, [2012 is still here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2012/), [2013 is still here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2013/), [2014 is still here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2014/))

What to do?

- Remove all the wwdc 2010-2011 broken links?
- Replace the links with illegal Chinese rips from http://www.cloudyouku.com/, like [this one](http://www.cloudyouku.com/video/?vid=XMzQ0ODI1MjA0)?
- Replace the links with Text transcripts from https://asciiwwdc.com/, like [this one](https://asciiwwdc.com/2010/sessions/123)?

Impacted posts:

- 28 results from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3adeveloper.apple.com%2fvideos%2farchive
- 192 results from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Adeveloper.apple.com%2Fvideos%2Fwwdc%2F2010%2F
- 319 results from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Adeveloper.apple.com%2Fvideos%2Fwwdc%2F2011%2F

Comment: Is it an option to just remove the broken links, and if the post relied on them delete it? Just replacing it with some other links just seems like postponing the issue. If someone can google their way to an old SO post they should be able to google their way to a video of a talk as well if they know it's title and what conference it's from?

Comment: @ivarni and when it had no links to begin with? Like https://stackoverflow.com/a/6213312

Comment: @Cœur that entire question is off-topic. It's better to close and delete in a couple days

Comment: @Cœur That one was an easy delete, but if it didn't have any links to begin with and just referenced the talk then there's no link that can break. That's what I suggested doing for all of them if the content of the post still stands on it own. Then the community don't have to keep updating links as they break and whoever wants to watch the video can use a search engine to find it. Maybe that's a bad solution, I dunno.

Comment: Companies with a big pile of cash keep breaking the internet and then we can fix their screw-ups for free. I hope they bought at least a couple of SO Enterprise licenses to cover for the inconvenience.

Comment: @rene Yes, and Microsoft is an offender too. They didn't even provide redirects until recently (for the `technet.microsoft.com` to `docs.microsoft.com` move they finally did - [example](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849965.aspx)). Perhaps they are still in denial about this whole Internet thing.

Comment: Stack Overflow the company *should* really reach out directly to Apple and ask if they can offer a mirror site for these old videos or add them back, with the number of posts who now have dead links.

Comment: @PeterMortensen They still haven't done it for bugs/issues AFAIK :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit nope, when they rebooted their feedback system (for some reason) all of the connect stuff was just deleted, with no backup as far as I can tell

Comment: @jrh It feels almost criminal (albeit not in the legal sense) :(

Comment: Are any of the videos available on the Wayback Machine (https://web.archive.org/)?

Comment: Welcome to the Humpty Dumpty Era, where a word means whatever we say it means, neither more nor less, and history is subject to deletion at any time. Please check your continuity at the door.

Comment: I think we can safely say we don't want to use the illegal Chinese rips.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hosting the videos on the Wayback Machine would go against https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/terms/site.html (assuming that the videos followed those ToS). Killing links and preventing mirroring, what a class act.

Answer (score 54):

Thanks to matt who figured out that the media are still available if we're aware of the exact URL. Using the Wayback Machine, we're able to relist the videos.

---

### WWDC 2010

Based on https://web.archive.org/web/20150905210920/https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/, we can list those:

> - Accessibility on iPhone OS · Session 122
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_122__accessibility_on_iphone_os.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_122__accessibility_on_iphone_os.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/122__accessibility_on_iphone_os.pdf)
> - Accessing Shared Contact Information · Session 119
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_119__accessing_shared_contact_information.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_119__accessing_shared_contact_information.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/119__accessing_shared_contact_information.pdf)
> - Adding Touch and Gesture Detection to Web Pages on iPhone OS · Session 508
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_508__adding_touch_and_gesture_detection_to_web_pages_on_iphone_os.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_508__adding_touch_and_gesture_detection_to_web_pages_on_iphone_os.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/508__adding_touch_and_gesture_detection_to_web_pages_on_iphone_os.pdf)
> - Adopting Multitasking on iPhone OS, Part 1 · Session 105
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_105__adopting_multitasking_on_iphone_os_part_1.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_105__adopting_multitasking_on_iphone_os_part_1.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/105__adopting_multitasking_on_iphone_os_part_1.pdf)
> - Adopting Multitasking on iPhone OS, Part 2 · Session 109
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_109__adopting_multitasking_on_iphone_os_part_2.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_109__adopting_multitasking_on_iphone_os_part_2.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/109__adopting_multitasking_on_iphone_os_part_2.pdf)
> - Advanced Cocoa Text Tips and Tricks · Session 114
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_114__advanced_cocoa_text_tips_and_tricks.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_114__advanced_cocoa_text_tips_and_tricks.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/114__advanced_cocoa_text_tips__tricks.pdf)
> - Advanced Gesture Recognition · Session 121
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_121__advanced_gesture_recognition.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_121__advanced_gesture_recognition.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/121__advanced_gesture_recognition.pdf)
> - Advanced Memory Analysis with Instruments · Session 311
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_311__advanced_memory_analysis_with_instruments.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_311__advanced_memory_analysis_with_instruments.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/311__advanced_memory_analysis_with_instruments.pdf)
> - Advanced Objective-C and Garbage Collection Techniques · Session 144
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_144__advanced_objectivec_and_garbage_collection_techniques.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_144__advanced_objectivec_and_garbage_collection_techniques.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/144__advanced_objectivec_and_garbage_collection_techniques.pdf)
> - Advanced Performance Analysis with Instruments · Session 309
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_309__advanced_performance_analysis_with_instruments.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_309__advanced_performance_analysis_with_instruments.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/309__advanced_performance_analysis_with_instruments.pdf)
> - Advanced Performance Optimization on iPhone OS, Part 1 · Session 135
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_135__advanced_performance_optimization_on_iphone_os_part_1.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_135__advanced_performance_optimization_on_iphone_os_part_1.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/135__advanced_performance_optimization_on_iphone_os_part_1.pdf)
> - Advanced Performance Optimization on iPhone OS, Part 2 · Session 147
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_147__advanced_performance_optimization_on_iphone_os_part_2.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_147__advanced_performance_optimization_on_iphone_os_part_2.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/147__advanced_performance_optimization_on_iphone_os_part_2.pdf)
> - Advanced Text Handling for iPhone OS · Session 110
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_110__advanced_text_handling_for_iphone_os.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_110__advanced_text_handling_for_iphone_os.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/110__advanced_text_handling_for_iphone_os.pdf)
> - Advances in HTTP Live Streaming · Session 403
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_403__advances_in_http_live_streaming.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_403__advances_in_http_live_streaming.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/403__advances_in_http_live_streaming.pdf)
> - App Publishing with iTunes Connect · Session 310
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_310__app_publishing_with_itunes_connect.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_310__app_publishing_with_itunes_connect.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/310__app_publishing_with_itunes_connect.pdf)
> - Apple WWDC 2010 Keynote Address · Session 138
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/apple_wwdc_2010_keynote_address.mov)
> - API Design for Cocoa and Cocoa Touch
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_138__api_design_for_cocoa_and_cocoa_touch.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_138__api_design_for_cocoa_and_cocoa_touch.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/138__api_design_for_cocoa_and_cocoa_touch.pdf)
> - Audio Development for iPhone OS, Part 1 · Session 412
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_412__audio_development_for_iphone_os_part_1.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_412__audio_development_for_iphone_os_part_1.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/412__audio_development_for_iphone_os_part_1.pdf)
> - Audio Development for iPhone OS, Part 2 · Session 413
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_413__audio_development_for_iphone_os_part_2.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_413__audio_development_for_iphone_os_part_2.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/413__audio_development_for_iphone_os_part_2.pdf)
> - Automating User Interface Testing with Instruments · Session 306
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_306__automating_user_interface_testing_with_instruments.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_306__automating_user_interface_testing_with_instruments.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/306__automating_user_interface_testing_with_instruments.pdf)
> - Automating the Creation of iPad Content · Session 302
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_302__automating_the_creation_of_ipad_content.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_302__automating_the_creation_of_ipad_content.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/302__automating_the_creation_of_ipad_content.pdf)
> - Building Animation Driven Interfaces · Session 123
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_123__building_animation_driven_interfaces.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_123__building_animation_driven_interfaces.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/123__building_animation_driven_interfaces.pdf)
> - Building a Server-driven User Experience · Session 117
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_117__building_a_serverdriven_user_experience.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_117__building_a_serverdriven_user_experience.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/117__building_a_serverdriven_user_experience.pdf)
> - Building and Distributing Your App with Xcode 4 · Session 314
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_314__building_and_distributing_your_app_with_xcode_4.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_314__building_and_distributing_your_app_with_xcode_4.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/314__building_and_distributing_your_app_with_xcode_4.pdf)
> - CSS Effects, Part 1: UI Elements and Navigation · Session 503
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_503__css_effects_part_1__ui_elements_and_navigation.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_503__css_effects_part_1__ui_elements_and_navigation.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/503__css_effects_part_1__ui_elements_and_navigation.pdf)
> - CSS Effects, Part 2: Galleries and 3D Effects · Session 504
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_504__css_effects_part_2__galleries_and_3d_effects.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_504__css_effects_part_2__galleries_and_3d_effects.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/504__css_effects_part_2__galleries_and_3d_effects.pdf)
> - Calendar Integration with Event Kit · Session 136
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_136__calendar_integration_with_event_kit.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_136__calendar_integration_with_event_kit.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/136__calendar_integration_with_event_kit.pdf)
> - Cocoa Tips and Tricks · Session 107
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_107__cocoa_tips_and_tricks.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_107__cocoa_tips_and_tricks.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/107__cocoa_tips_and_tricks.pdf)
> - Core Animation in Practice, Part 1 · Session 424
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_424__core_animation_in_practice_part_1.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_424__core_animation_in_practice_part_1.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/424__core_animation_in_practice_part_1.pdf)
> - Core Animation in Practice, Part 2 · Session 425
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_425__core_animation_in_practice_part_2.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_425__core_animation_in_practice_part_2.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/425__core_animation_in_practice_part_2.pdf)
> - Core Image Effects and Optimization · Session 426
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_426__core_image_effects_and_optimization.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_426__core_image_effects_and_optimization.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/426__core_image_effects_and_optimization.pdf)
> - Core OS Networking · Session 200
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_200__core_os_networking.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_200__core_os_networking.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/200__core_os_networking.pdf)
> - Crafting Custom Cocoa Views · Session 141
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_141__crafting_custom_cocoa_views.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_141__crafting_custom_cocoa_views.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/141__crafting_custom_cocoa_views.pdf)
> - Creating Content With iAd JS, Part 1 · Session 510
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_510__creating_content_with_iad_js_part_1.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_510__creating_content_with_iad_js_part_1.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/510__creating_content_with_iad_js_part_1.pdf)
> - Creating Content With iAd JS, Part 2 · Session 511
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_511__creating_content_with_iad_js_part_2.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_511__creating_content_with_iad_js_part_2.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/511__creating_content_with_iad_js_part_2.pdf)
> - Creating Extensions for Safari, Part 1 · Session 505
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_505__creating_extensions_for_safari_part_1.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_505__creating_extensions_for_safari_part_1.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/505__creating_extensions_for_safari_part_1.pdf)
> - Creating Extensions for Safari, Part 2 · Session 506
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_506__creating_extensions_for_safari_part_2.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_506__creating_extensions_for_safari_part_2.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/506__creating_extensions_for_safari_part_2.pdf)
> - Creating Info Graphics with Standard Web Technologies · Session 509
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_509__creating_info_graphics_with_standard_web_technologies.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_509__creating_info_graphics_with_standard_web_technologies.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/509__creating_info_graphics_with_standard_web_technologies.pdf)
> - Creating Secure Applications · Session 204
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_204__creating_secure_applications.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_204__creating_secure_applications.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/204__creating_secure_applications.pdf)
> - Customizing Maps with Overlays · Session 127
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_127__customizing_maps_with_overlays.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_127__customizing_maps_with_overlays.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/127__customizing_maps_with_overlays.pdf)
> - Debugging with Xcode 4 and LLDB · Session 316
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_316__debugging_with_xcode_4_and_lldb.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_316__debugging_with_xcode_4_and_lldb.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/316__debugging_with_xcode_4_and_lldb.pdf)
> - Delivering Audio and Video Using Web Standards, Part 1 · Session 501
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_501__delivering_audio_and_video_using_web_standards_part_1.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_501__delivering_audio_and_video_using_web_standards_part_1.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/501__delivering_audio_and_video_using_web_standards_part_1.pdf)
> - Delivering Audio and Video Using Web Standards, Part 2 · Session 502
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_502__delivering_audio_and_video_using_web_standards_part_2.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_502__delivering_audio_and_video_using_web_standards_part_2.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/502__delivering_audio_and_video_using_web_standards_part_2.pdf)
> - Designing Apps with Interface Builder · Session 305
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_305__designing_apps_with_interface_builder.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_305__designing_apps_with_interface_builder.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/305__designing_apps_with_interface_builder.pdf)
> - Designing Apps with Scroll Views · Session 104
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_104__designing_apps_with_scroll_views.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_104__designing_apps_with_scroll_views.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/104__designing_apps_with_scroll_views.pdf)
> - Developer Tools State of the Union · Session 300
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_300__developer_tools_state_of_the_union.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_300__developer_tools_state_of_the_union.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/reference_library/wwdc_2010_slides/session_300__developer_tools_state_of_the_union.pdf)
> - Developing Applications that work with iPhone OS Accessories · Session 201
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_201__developing_applications_that_work_with_iphone_os_accessories.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_201__developing_applications_that_work_with_iphone_os_accessories.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/201__developing_applications_that_work_with_iphone_os_accessories.pdf)
> - Developing Your App with Xcode 4 · Session 308
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_308__developing_your_app_with_xcode_4.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_308__developing_your_app_with_xcode_4.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/308__developing_your_app_with_xcode_4.pdf)
> - Discovering AV Foundation · Session 405
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_405__discovering_av_foundation.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_405__discovering_av_foundation.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/405__discovering_av_foundation.pdf)
> - Editing Media with AV Foundation · Session 407
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_407__editing_media_with_av_foundation.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_407__editing_media_with_av_foundation.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/407__editing_media_with_av_foundation.pdf)
> - Fundamentals of Digital Audio for Mac OS X and iPhone OS · Session 411
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_411__fundamentals_of_digital_audio_for_mac_os_x_and_iphone_os.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_411__fundamentals_of_digital_audio_for_mac_os_x_and_iphone_os.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/411__fundamentals_of_digital_audio_for_mac_os_x_and_iphone_os.pdf)
> - Future Proofing your Application · Session 130
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_130__future_proofing_your_application.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_130__future_proofing_your_application.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/130__future_proofing_your_application.pdf)
> - Game Center Techniques, Part 1 · Session 408
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_408__game_center_techniques_part_1.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_408__game_center_techniques_part_1.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/408__game_center_techniques_part_1.pdf)
> - Game Center Techniques, Part 2 · Session 410
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_410__game_center_techniques_part_2.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_410__game_center_techniques_part_2.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/410__game_center_techniques_part_2.pdf)
> - Game Design and Development for iPhone OS, Part 1 · Session 401
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_401__game_design_and_development_for_iphone_os_part_1.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_401__game_design_and_development_for_iphone_os_part_1.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/401__game_design_and_development_for_iphone_os_part_1.pdf)
> - Game Design and Development for iPhone OS, Part 2 · Session 402
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_402__game_design_and_development_for_iphone_os_part_2.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_402__game_design_and_development_for_iphone_os_part_2.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/402__game_design_and_development_for_iphone_os_part_2.pdf)
> - Getting the Most Out of Safari Integrated Developer Tools · Session 507
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_507__getting_the_most_out_of_safari_integrated_developer_tools.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_507__getting_the_most_out_of_safari_integrated_developer_tools.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/507__getting_the_most_out_of_safari_integrated_developer_tools.pdf)
> - Graphics and Media State of the Union · Session 400
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_400__graphics_and_media_state_of_the_union.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_400__graphics_and_media_state_of_the_union.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/400__graphics_and_media_state_of_the_union.pdf)
> - Harnessing OpenCL in Your Application · Session 416
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_416__harnessing_opencl_in_your_application.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_416__harnessing_opencl_in_your_application.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/416__harnessing_opencl_in_your_application.pdf)
> - I/O Kit Device Drivers for Mac OS X · Session 203
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_203__i_o_kit_device_drivers_for_mac_os_x.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_203__i_o_kit_device_drivers_for_mac_os_x.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/203__io_kit_device_drivers_for_mac_os_x.pdf)
> - Implementing Local and Push Notifications · Session 129
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_129__implementing_local_and_push_notifications.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_129__implementing_local_and_push_notifications.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/129__implementing_local_and_push_notifications.pdf)
> - Incorporating the Camera and Photo Library in your App · Session 421
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_421__incorporating_the_camera_and_photo_library_in_your_app.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_421__incorporating_the_camera_and_photo_library_in_your_app.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/421__incorporating_the_camera_and_photo_library_in_your_app.pdf)
> - Integrating Ads with iAd · Session 112
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_112__integrating_ads_with_iad.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_112__integrating_ads_with_iad.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/112__integrating_ads_with_iad.pdf)
> - Internationalizing Data on Mac and iPhone · Session 125
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_125__internationalizing_data_on_mac_and_iphone.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_125__internationalizing_data_on_mac_and_iphone.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/125__internationalizing_data_on_mac_and_iphone.pdf)
> - Introducing Blocks and Grand Central Dispatch on iPhone · Session 206
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_206__introducing_blocks_and_grand_central_dispatch_on_iphone.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_206__introducing_blocks_and_grand_central_dispatch_on_iphone.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/206__introducing_blocks_and_grand_central_dispatch_on_iphone.pdf)
> - Introducing Xcode 4 · Session 307
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_307__introducing_xcode_4.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_307__introducing_xcode_4.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/307__introducing_xcode_4.pdf)
> - Introduction to Game Center · Session 404
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_404__introduction_to_game_center.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_404__introduction_to_game_center.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/404__introduction_to_game_center.pdf)
> - iPad and iPhone User Interface Design · Session 103
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_103__ipad_and_iphone_user_interface_design.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_103__ipad_and_iphone_user_interface_design.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/103__ipad_and_iphone_user_interface_design.pdf)
> - iPad Development Overview · Session 111
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_111__ipad_development_overview.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_111__ipad_development_overview.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/111__ipad_development_overview.pdf)
> - Key Event Handling in Cocoa Applications · Session 145
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_145__key_event_handling_in_cocoa_applications.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_145__key_event_handling_in_cocoa_applications.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/145__key_event_handling_in_cocoa_applications.pdf)
> - LLVM Technologies in Depth · Session 313
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_313__llvm_technologies_in_depth.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_313__llvm_technologies_in_depth.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/313__llvm_technologies_in_depth.pdf)
> - Launch-on-Demand · Session 210
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_210__launchondemand.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_210__launchondemand.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/210__launchondemand.pdf)
> - Managing Mobile Devices · Session 108
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_108__managing_mobile_devices.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_108__managing_mobile_devices.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/108__managing_mobile_devices.pdf)
> - Mastering Core Data · Session 118
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_118__mastering_core_data.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_118__mastering_core_data.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/118__mastering_core_data.pdf)
> - Mastering Table Views · Session 128
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_128__mastering_table_views.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_128__mastering_table_views.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/128__mastering_table_views.pdf)
> - Mastering Xcode for iPhone OS Development, Part 1 · Session 301
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_301__mastering_xcode_for_iphone_os_development_part_1.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_301__mastering_xcode_for_iphone_os_development_part_1.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/301__mastering_xcode_for_iphone_os_development_part_1.pdf)
> - Mastering Xcode for iPhone OS Development, Part 2 · Session 303
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_303__mastering_xcode_for_iphone_os_development_part_2.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_303__mastering_xcode_for_iphone_os_development_part_2.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/303__mastering_xcode_for_iphone_os_development_part_2.pdf)
> - Maximizing OpenCL Performance · Session 418
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_418__maximizing_opencl_performance.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_418__maximizing_opencl_performance.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/418__maximizing_opencl_performance.pdf)
> - Model-View-Controller for iPhone OS · Session 116
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_116__modelviewcontroller_for_iphone_os_1.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_116__modelviewcontroller_for_iphone_os.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/116__modelviewcontroller_for_iphone_os.pdf)
> - Network Apps for iPhone OS, Part 1 · Session 207
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_207__network_apps_for_iphone_os_part_1.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_207__network_apps_for_iphone_os_part_1.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/207__network_apps_for_iphone_os_part_1.pdf)
> - Network Apps for iPhone OS, Part 2 · Session 208
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_208__network_apps_for_iphone_os_part_2.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_208__network_apps_for_iphone_os_part_2.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/208__network_apps_for_iphone_os_part_2.pdf)
> - OpenGL ES Overview for iPhone OS · Session 415
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_415__opengl_es_overview_for_iphone_os.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_415__opengl_es_overview_for_iphone_os.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/415__opengl_es_overview_for_iphone_os.pdf)
> - OpenGL ES Shading and Advanced Rendering · Session 417
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_417__opengl_es_shading_and_advanced_rendering.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_417__opengl_es_shading_and_advanced_rendering.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/417__opengl_es_shading__advanced_rendering.pdf)
> - OpenGL ES Tuning and Optimization · Session 419
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_419__opengl_es_tuning_and_optimization.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_419__opengl_es_tuning_and_optimization.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/419__opengl_es_tuning__optimization.pdf)
> - OpenGL Essential Design Practices · Session 414
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_414__opengl_essential_design_practices.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_414__opengl_essential_design_practices.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/414__opengl_essential_design_practices.pdf)
> - OpenGL for Mac OS X · Session 420
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_420__opengl_for_mac_os_x.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_420__opengl_for_mac_os_x.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/420__opengl_for_mac_os_x.pdf)
> - Optimize your iPhone App for the Retina Display · Session 134
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_134__optimize_your_iphone_app_for_the_retina_display.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_134__optimize_your_iphone_app_for_the_retina_display.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/134__optimize_your_iphone_app_for_the_retina_display.pdf)
> - Optimizing Core Data Performance on iPhone OS · Session 137
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_137__optimizing_core_data_performance_on_iphone_os.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_137__optimizing_core_data_performance_on_iphone_os.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/137__optimizing_core_data_performance_on_iphone_os.pdf)
> - Performance Optimization on iPhone OS · Session 131
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_131__performance_optimization_on_iphone_os.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_131__performance_optimization_on_iphone_os.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/131__performance_optimization_on_iphone_os.pdf)
> - Safari, Internet and Web State of the Union · Session 500
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_500__safari_internet_and_web_state_of_the_union.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_500__safari_internet_and_web_state_of_the_union.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/500__safari_internet__web_state_of_the_union.pdf)
> - Securing Application Data · Session 209
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_209__securing_application_data.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_209__securing_application_data.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/209__securing_application_data.pdf)
> - Sensing Device Motion in iOS 4 · Session 423
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_423__sensing_device_motion_in_ios_4.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_423__sensing_device_motion_in_ios_4.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/423__sensing_device_motion.pdf)
> - Simplifying Networking Using Bonjour · Session 205
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_205__simplifying_networking_using_bonjour.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_205__simplifying_networking_using_bonjour.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/205__simplifying_networking_using_bonjour.pdf)
> - Simplifying Touch Event Handling with Gesture Recognizers · Session 120
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_120__simplifying_touch_event_handling_with_gesture_recognizers.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_120__simplifying_touch_event_handling_with_gesture_recognizers.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/120__simplifying_touch_event_handling_with_gesture_recognizers.pdf)
> - Simplifying iPhone App Development with Grand Central Dispatch · Session 211
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_211__simplifying_iphone_app_development_with_grand_central_dispatch.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_211__simplifying_iphone_app_development_with_grand_central_dispatch.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/211__simplifying_iphone_app_development_with_grand_central_dispatch_.pdf)
> - Taking Advantage of Multiple GPUs · Session 422
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_422__taking_advantage_of_multiple_gpus.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_422__taking_advantage_of_multiple_gpus.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/422__taking_advantage_of_multiple_gpus.pdf)
> - The Accelerate framework for iPhone OS · Session 202
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_202__the_accelerate_framework_for_iphone_os.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_202__the_accelerate_framework_for_iphone_os.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/202__the_accelerate_framework_for_iphone_os.pdf)
> - Understanding Crash Reports on iPhone OS · Session 317
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_317__understanding_crash_reports_on_iphone_os.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_317__understanding_crash_reports_on_iphone_os.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/317__understanding_crash_reports_on_iphone_os.pdf)
> - Understanding Document Interaction Controller · Session 106
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_106__understanding_document_interaction_controller.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_106__understanding_document_interaction_controller.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/106__understanding_document_interaction_controller.pdf)
> - Understanding Foundation · Session 124
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_124__understanding_foundation.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_124__understanding_foundation.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/124__understanding_foundation.pdf)
> - Usable by Everybody: Design Principles for Accessibility on Mac OS X · Session 100
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_100__usable_by_everybody__design_principles_for_accessibility_on_mac_os_x.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_100__usable_by_everybody__design_principles_for_accessibility_on_mac_os_x.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/100__usable_by_everybody__design_principles_for_accessibility_on_mac_os_x.pdf)
> - Using Core Location in iOS 4 · Session 115
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_115__using_core_location_in_ios_4.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_115__using_core_location_in_ios_4.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/115__using_core_location_in_iphone_os_4.pdf)
> - Using HTML5 Offline Storage · Session 512
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_512__using_html5_offline_storage.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_512__using_html5_offline_storage.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/512__using_html5_offline_storage.pdf)
> - Using Interface Builder in Xcode 4 · Session 315
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_315__using_interface_builder_in_xcode_4.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_315__using_interface_builder_in_xcode_4.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/315__using_interface_builder_in_xcode_4.pdf)
> - Using iTunes and App Store Affiliate Tools and Technologies · Session 133
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_133__using_itunes_and_app_store_affiliate_tools_and_technologies.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_133__using_itunes_and_app_store_affiliate_tools_and_technologies.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/133__using_itunes__app_store_affiliate_tools_and_technologies.pdf)
> - Using the Camera with AV Foundation · Session 409
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_409__using_the_camera_with_av_foundation.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_409__using_the_camera_with_av_foundation.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/409__using_the_camera_with_av_foundation.pdf)
> - What's New in Cocoa Touch · Session 101
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_101__whats_new_in_cocoa_touch.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_101__whats_new_in_cocoa_touch.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/101__whats_new_in_cocoa_touch.pdf)
> - What's New in Foundation for iOS 4 · Session 102
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_102__whats_new_in_foundation_for_ios_4_1.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_102__whats_new_in_foundation_for_ios_4.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/102__whats_new_in_foundation_for_iphone_os_4.pdf)
> - What's New in Instruments · Session 304
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_304__whats_new_in_instruments.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_304__whats_new_in_instruments.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/304__whats_new_in_instruments.pdf)
> - What's New in the LLVM Compiler · Session 312
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_312__whats_new_in_the_llvm_compiler.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_312__whats_new_in_the_llvm_compiler.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/312__whats_new_in_the_llvm_compiler.pdf)
> - Working Effectively with Objective-C on iPhone OS · Session 113
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_113__working_effectively_with_objectivec_on_iphone_os.mov) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_113__working_effectively_with_objectivec_on_iphone_os.mov) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/113__working_effectively_with_objectivec_on_iphone_os.pdf)

---

### WWDC 2011

Based on https://web.archive.org/web/20150905210920/https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/, we can list those:

> - Keynote
>     [?]
> - Adopting Multitasking in Your App · Session 320
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/320/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_320__adopting_multitasking_in_your_app.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_320__adopting_multitasking_in_your_app.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/320_adopting_multitasking_.pdf)
> - Advanced HTML5 Media Controllers in Safari · Session 502
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/502/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_502__advanced_html5_media_controllers_in_safari.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_502__advanced_html5_media_controllers_in_safari.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/502_advanced_html5_media_controllers_in_safari.pdf)
> - Advanced ScrollView Techniques · Session 104
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/104/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_104__advanced_scroll_view_techniques.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_104__advanced_scroll_view_techniques.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/104_advanced_scroll_view_techniques.pdf)
> - Advanced Text Processing · Session 128
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/128/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_128__advanced_text_processing.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_128__advanced_text_processing.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/128_advancedtextprocessing.pdf)
> - Advances in OpenGL ES for iOS 5 · Session 414
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/414/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_414__advances_in_opengl_es_for_ios_5.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_414__advances_in_opengl_es_for_ios_5.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/414_advances_in_opengl_es_for_ios_5.pdf)
> - Advances in OpenGL for Mac OS X Lion · Session 420
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/420/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_420__advances_in_opengl_for_mac_os_lion.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_420__advances_in_opengl_for_mac_os_lion.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/420advances_in_opengl_for_mac_os_lion.pdf)
> - AirPlay and External Displays in iOS apps · Session 406
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/406/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_406__airplay_and_external_displays_in_ios_apps.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_406__airplay_and_external_displays_in_ios_apps.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/406_airplay_and_external_displays_in_ios_apps.pdf)
> - App Sandbox and the Mac App Store · Session 204
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/204/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_204__app_sandbox_and_the_mac_app_store.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_204__app_sandbox_and_the_mac_app_store.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/204_app_sandbox_and_the_mac_app_store.pdf)
> - Apple Platforms Kickoff
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/601/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/apple_platforms_kickoff.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/601_wwdc_platforms_kickoff_.pdf)
> - Audio Development for Games · Session 404
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/404/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_404__audio_development_for_games.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_404__audio_development_for_games.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/404_audio_development_for_games.pdf)
> - Audio Session Management for iOS · Session 413
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/413/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_413__audio_session_management_for_ios.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_413__audio_session_management_for_ios.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/413_audio_session_management_for_ios.pdf)
> - Auto Save and Versions in Mac OS X 10.7 Lion · Session 107
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/107/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_107__autosave_and_versions_in_mac_os_x_10.7_lion.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_107__autosave_and_versions_in_mac_os_x_10.7_lion.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/107_autosave_and_versions_in_mac_os_x_10.7_lion.pdf)
> - Best Practices for OpenGL ES Apps in iOS · Session 418
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/418/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_418__best_practices_for_opengl_es_on_ios.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_418__best_practices_for_opengl_es_on_ios.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/418_best_practices_for_opengl_es_on_ios.pdf)
> - Blocks and Grand Central Dispatch in Practice · Session 308
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/308/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_308__blocks_and_grand_central_dispatch_in_practice.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_308__blocks_and_grand_central_dispatch_in_practice.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/308_blocks_and_grand_central_dispatch.pdf)
> - Bonjour Network Discovery and Connectivity · Session 211
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/211/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_211__bonjour_network_discovery_and_connectivity.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_211__bonjour_network_discovery_and_connectivity.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/211_bonjour_network_discovery_and_connectivity.pdf)
> - Building Newsstand Apps · Session 504
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/504/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_504__building_newsstand_apps.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_504__building_newsstand_apps.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/504_building_newsstand_apps.pdf)
> - Building iAd Rich Media Ads with iAd Producer · Session 506
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/506/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_506__building_iad_rich_media_ads_with_iad_producer.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_506__building_iad_rich_media_ads_with_iad_producer.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/506_building_iad_rich_media_ads_with_iad_producer.pdf)
> - Capturing from the Camera using AV Foundation on iOS 5 · Session 419
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/419/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_419__capture_from_camera_using_avfoundation_on_ios.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_419__capture_from_camera_using_avfoundation_on_ios.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/419_capture_from_camera_using_avfoundation_on_ios.pdf)
> - Cocoa Autolayout · Session 103
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/103/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_103__cocoa_autolayout.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_103__cocoa_autolayout.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/103_cocoa_autolayout.pdf)
> - Combining Web Accessibility and Automation on iOS · Session 519
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/519/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_519__combining_web_accessibility_and_automation_on_ios.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_519__combining_web_accessibility_and_automation_on_ios.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/519_web_accessibilty_and_automation.pdf)
> - Core Animation Essentials · Session 421
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/421/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_421__core_animation_essentials.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_421__core_animation_essentials.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/421_core_animation_essentials.pdf)
> - Core OS Networking In-Depth · Session 205
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/205/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_205__core_os_networking_indepth.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_205__core_os_networking_indepth.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/205_core_os_networking.pdf)
> - Core OS Networking, Key Principles · Session 200
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/200/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_200__core_os_networking.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_200__core_os_networking.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/200_coreos_networking.pdf)
> - Customizing the Appearance of UIKit Controls · Session 114
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/114/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_114__customizing_the_appearance_of_uikit_controls.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_114__customizing_the_appearance_of_uikit_controls.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/114_customizing_the_appearance_of_uikit_controls.pdf)
> - Design Patterns to Simplify Mac Accessibility · Session 127
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/127/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_127__design_patterns_to_simplify_mac_accessibility.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_127__design_patterns_to_simplify_mac_accessibility.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/127_design_patterns_to_simplify_mac_accessibility.pdf)
> - Designing User Interfaces for iOS and Mac OS X Apps · Session 110
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/110/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_110__designing_user_interfaces_for_ios_and_mac_os_x_apps.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_110__designing_user_interfaces_for_ios_and_mac_os_x_apps.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/110_designing_user_interfaces_for_ios_and_mac_apps.pdf)
> - Developer Tools Kickoff · Session 300
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/300/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_300__developer_tools_kickoff.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_300__developer_tools_kickoff.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/300developer_tools_kickoff.pdf)
> - Device Management and App Submission with Xcode 4 · Session 317
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/317/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_317__device_management_and_app_submission_with_xcode_4.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_317__device_management_and_app_submission_with_xcode_4.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/317_device_management_app_submission_w_xcode.pdf)
> - Effective Debugging with Xcode 4 · Session 319
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/319/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_319__effective_debugging_with_xcode_4.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_319__effective_debugging_with_xcode_4.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/319_effective_debugging_with_xcode_4.pdf)
> - Essential Game Technologies for iOS, Pt 1 · Session 402
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/402/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_402__essential_game_technologies_for_ios_part_1.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_402__essential_game_technologies_for_ios_part_1.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/402_ios_game__part_1_repeat.pdf)
> - Essential Game Technologies for iOS, Pt 2 · Session 403
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/403/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_403__essential_game_technologies_for_ios_part_2.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_403__essential_game_technologies_for_ios_part_2.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/403_iosgamespart2_repeat.pdf)
> - Exploring AV Foundation · Session 405
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/405/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_405__exploring_av_foundation.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_405__exploring_av_foundation.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/405_exploring_av_foundation.pdf)
> - Full Screen and Aqua Changes · Session 113
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/113/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_113__full_screen_and_aqua_changes.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_113__full_screen_and_aqua_changes.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/113_full_screen_and_aqua_changes.pdf)
> - Getting Your Apps Ready for China and other Hot New Markets · Session 131
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/131/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_131__getting_your_apps_ready_for_china_and_hot_markets.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_131__getting_your_apps_ready_for_china_and_hot_markets.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/131_getting_your_apps_ready_for_china_and_hot_markets.pdf)
> - Graphics, Media, and Games Kickoff · Session 400
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/400/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_400__graphics_media_and_games_kickoff.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_400__graphics_media_and_games_kickoff.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/400_graphics_and_media_kickoff.pdf)
> - HTTP Live Streaming Update · Session 408
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/408/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_408__http_live_streaming_update.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_408__http_live_streaming_update.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/408_http_live_streaming_update.pdf)
> - Hidden Gems for Web Apps · Session 503
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/503/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_503__hidden_gems_for_web_apps.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_503__hidden_gems_for_web_apps.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/503_hidden_gems_for_web_apps.pdf)
> - Implementing UIViewController Containment · Session 102
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/102/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_102__implementing_uiviewcontroller_containment.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_102__implementing_uiviewcontroller_containment.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/102_implementing_uiviewcontroller_containment.pdf)
> - Improving the Stability of Your Apps · Session 123
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/123/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_123__improving_the_stability_of_your_apps.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_123__improving_the_stability_of_your_apps.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/123_improving_the_stability_of_your_apps.pdf)
> - In-App Purchase for iOS and Mac OS X · Session 510
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/510/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_510__inapp_purchase_for_ios_and_mac_os_x.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_510__inapp_purchase_for_ios_and_mac_os_x.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/510_inapp_purchase_for_ios_and_mac_os_x.pdf)
> - Inside the Accelerate Framework for iOS · Session 209
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/209/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_209__inside_the_accelerate_framework_for_ios.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_209__inside_the_accelerate_framework_for_ios.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/209_inside_the_accelerate_framework_for_ios.pdf)
> - Introducing AV Foundation Capture For Lion · Session 417
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/417/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_417__introducing_avfoundation_capture_for_lion.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_417__introducing_avfoundation_capture_for_lion.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/417_introducing_avfoundation_capture_for_lion.pdf)
> - Introducing App Sandbox · Session 203
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/203/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_203__introducing_app_sandbox.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_203__introducing_app_sandbox.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/203_introducing_app_sandbox.pdf)
> - Introducing Automatic Reference Counting · Session 323
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/323/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_323__introducing_automatic_reference_counting.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_323__introducing_automatic_reference_counting.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/323_intro_to_arc_304repeat.pdf)
> - Introducing Interface Builder Storyboarding · Session 309
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/309/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_309__introducing_interface_builder_storyboarding.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_309__introducing_interface_builder_storyboarding.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/309_introducing_interface_builder_storyboarding.pdf)
> - Introducing XPC · Session 206
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/206/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_206__introducing_xpc.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_206__introducing_xpc.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/206_introducing_xpc.pdf)
> - Introduction to Game Center · Session 407
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/407/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_407__introduction_to_game_center.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_407__introduction_to_game_center.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/407_introduction_to_game_center.pdf)
> - LLVM Technologies in Depth · Session 316
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/316/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_316__llvm_technologies_in_depth.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_316__llvm_technologies_in_depth.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/316_llvmi_technologies_in_depth.pdf)
> - Latent Semantic Mapping: Exposing the Meaning behind Words and Documents · Session 136
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/136/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_136__latent_semantic_mapping.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_136__latent_semantic_mapping.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/136_latent_semantic_mapping.pdf)
> - Lion-Sized Automation
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/133/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_133__lionsized_automation.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/133_lionsized_automation.pdf)
> - Making the Most of Multi-Touch on iOS · Session 118
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/118/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_118__making_the_most_of_multitouch_on_ios.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_118__making_the_most_of_multitouch_on_ios.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/118_making_the_most_of_multitouch_on_ios.pdf)
> - Mastering Grand Central Dispatch · Session 210
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/210/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_210__mastering_grand_central_dispatch.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_210__mastering_grand_central_dispatch.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/210_mastering_grand_central_dispatch.pdf)
> - Mastering Schemes in Xcode 4 · Session 313
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/313/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_313__mastering_schemes_in_xcode_4.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_313__mastering_schemes_in_xcode_4.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/313_mastering_schemesin_xcode_4.pdf)
> - Mastering Source Control in Xcode 4 · Session 311
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/311/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_311__mastering_source_control_in_xcode.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_311__mastering_source_control_in_xcode.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/311_mastering_source_control_in_xcode.pdf)
> - Maximizing Productivity in Xcode 4 · Session 306
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/306/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_306__maximizing_productivity_in_xcode_4.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_306__maximizing_productivity_in_xcode_4.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/306_maximizing_productivity_in_xcode_4.pdf)
> - Migrating from GDB to LLDB · Session 321
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/321/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_321__migrating_from_gdb_to_lldb.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_321__migrating_from_gdb_to_lldb.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/321_migrating_from_gdb_to_lldb.pdf)
> - Moving to Apple LLVM compiler · Session 307
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/307/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_307__moving_to_the_apple_llvm_compiler.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_307__moving_to_the_apple_llvm_compiler.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/307_moving_to_the_llvm_compiler.pdf)
> - Multi-Player Gaming with Game Center · Session 410
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/410/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_410__multiplayer_gaming_with_game_center.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_410__multiplayer_gaming_with_game_center.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/410_multiplayer_gaming_with_game_center.pdf)
> - Music in iOS and Lion · Session 411
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/411/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_411__music_in_ios_and_lion.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_411__music_in_ios_and_lion.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/411_music_in_ios_and_lion.pdf)
> - Next Generation Cryptographic Services · Session 212
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/212/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_212__nextgeneration_cryptographic_services.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_212__nextgeneration_cryptographic_services.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/212_nextgeneration_cryptographic_services.pdf)
> - Objective-C Advancements In-Depth · Session 322
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/322/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_322__objectivec_advancements_in_depth.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_322__objectivec_advancements_in_depth.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/322_objectivec_advancements_in_depth.pdf)
> - Performing Calendar Calculations · Session 117
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/117/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_117__performing_calendar_calculations.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_117__performing_calendar_calculations.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/117performing_calendar_calculations.pdf)
> - Polishing your App: Tips and Tricks to Improve Responsiveness and Performance · Session 105
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/105/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_105__polishing_your_app.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_105__polishing_your_app.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/105_polishing_your_app.pdf)
> - Practical Drawing for iOS Developers · Session 129
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/129/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_129__practical_drawing_for_ios_developers.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_129__practical_drawing_for_ios_developers.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/129_practical_drawing_for_ios_developers.pdf)
> - Resume and Automatic Termination in Lion · Session 119
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/119/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_119__resume_and_automatic_termination.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_119__resume_and_automatic_termination.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/119_resume_and_automatic_termination.pdf)
> - Rich Text Editing in Safari on iOS · Session 511
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/511/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_511__rich_text_editing_in_safari_on_ios.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_511__rich_text_editing_in_safari_on_ios.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/511_rich_text_editing.pdf)
> - Scrolling, Swiping, Dragging: Now with more animation! · Session 115
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/115/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_115__scrolling_swiping_dragging.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_115__scrolling_swiping_dragging.m4v10) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/115_scrolling_swiping_dragging.pdf)
> - Securing Application Data · Session 208
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/208/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_208__securing_ios_applications.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_208__securing_ios_applications.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/208_securing_ios_applications.pdf)
> - Security Overview · Session 202
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/202/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_202__security_overview.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_202__security_overview.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/202_security_overview.pdf)
> - Storing Documents in iCloud using iOS 5 · Session 116
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/116/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_116__storing_documents_in_icloud_using_ios_5.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_116__storing_documents_in_icloud_using_ios_5.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/116_storing_documents_in_icloud_using_ios_5.pdf)
> - System-wide Previews on OSX and iOS · Session 106
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/106/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_106__systemwide_previews_on_osx_and_ios.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_106__systemwide_previews_on_osx_and_ios.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/106_systemwide_previews_on_osx_and_ios.pdf)
> - Taking Advantage of File Coordination · Session 109
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/109/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_109__taking_advantage_of_file_coordination.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_109__taking_advantage_of_file_coordination.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/109_taking_advantage_of_file_coordination.pdf)
> - Testing Your Location-Aware App Without Leaving Your Chair · Session 518
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/518/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_518__testing_your_locationaware_application.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_518__testing_your_locationaware_application.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/518_testing_your_locationaware_application.pdf)
> - Tools for Tuning OpenGL ES Apps on iOS · Session 416
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/416/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_416__tools_for_tuning_opengl_es_apps_on_ios.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_416__tools_for_tuning_opengl_es_apps_on_ios.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/416_tools_for_tining_opengl_es_apps_on_ios_.pdf)
> - Turn-Based Gaming with Game Center · Session 412
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/412/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_412__turnbased_gaming_with_game_center.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_412__turnbased_gaming_with_game_center.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/412_turnbased_gaming_with_game_center.pdf)
> - Twitter Integration · Session 124
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/124/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_124__twitter_integration.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_124__twitter_integration.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/124_twitter_integration.pdf)
> - UITableView Changes, Tips & Tricks · Session 125
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/125/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_125__uitableview_changes_tips_tricks.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_125__uitableview_changes_tips_tricks.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/125_uitableview_changes_tips_tricks.pdf)
> - Understanding And Optimizing Web Graphics · Session 508
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/508/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_508__understanding_and_optimizing_web_graphics.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_508__understanding_and_optimizing_web_graphics.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/508_understanding_and_optimizing_web_graphics.pdf)
> - Understanding Layout and Gestures in Safari on iOS and Lion · Session 516
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/516/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_516__understanding_layout_and_gestures.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_516__understanding_layout_and_gestures.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/516_understanding_layout_and_gestures.pdf)
> - Understanding UIKit Rendering · Session 121
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/121/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_121__understanding_uikit_rendering.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_121__understanding_uikit_rendering.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/121_understanding_uikit_rendering.pdf)
> - Userland Device Access · Session 207
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/207/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_207__userlevel_device_access.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_207__userlevel_device_access.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/207_user_level_device_access.pdf)
> - Using Core Image on iOS & Mac OS X · Session 422
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/422/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_422__using_core_image_on_ios_and_mac_os_x.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_422__using_core_image_on_ios_and_mac_os_x.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/422_using_core_image_on_ios_and_mac_os_x.pdf)
> - Using HTML5 Offline Storage · Session 515
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/515/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_515__using_html5_offline_storage.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_515__using_html5_offline_storage.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/515_using_html_offline_storage.pdf)
> - Using Interface Builder in Xcode 4 · Session 302
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/302/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_302__using_interface_builder_in_xcode_4.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_302__using_interface_builder_in_xcode_4.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/302_using_interface_builder_in_xcode_4.pdf)
> - Using Local And Push Notifications on iOS and Mac OS X · Session 517
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/517/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_517__using_local_and_push_notifications_on_ios_and_mac_os_x.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_517__using_local_and_push_notifications_on_ios_and_mac_os_x.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/517_using_local_and_push_notifications_on_mac_os_x.pdf)
> - View Based NSTableView Basic to Advanced · Session 120
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/120/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_120__view_based_nstableview.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_120__view_based_nstableview.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/120_view_based_tableview.pdf)
> - Visualizing Information Geographically with MapKit · Session 111
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/111/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_111__visualizing_information_geographically_with_mapkit.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_111__visualizing_information_geographically_with_mapkit.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/111_visualizing_information_geographically_using_map_kit.pdf)
> - What's New in App Publishing With iTunes Connect · Session 512
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/512/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_512__whats_new_in_app_publishing_with_itunes_connect.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_512__whats_new_in_app_publishing_with_itunes_connect.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/512_whats_new_in_app_publishing_with_itunes_connect.pdf)
> - What's New in CSS Effects and Animations · Session 509
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/509/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_509__whats_new_in_css_effects_and_animation.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_509__whats_new_in_css_effects_and_animation.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/509_whats_new_in_css_effects_and_animation.pdf)
> - What's New in Cocoa · Session 101
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/101/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_101__whats_new_in_cocoa.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_101__whats_new_in_cocoa.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/101_whats_new_in_cocoa.pdf)
> - What's New in Cocoa Touch · Session 100
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/100/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_100__whats_new_in_cocoa_touch.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_100__whats_new_in_cocoa_touch.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/100_whats_new_in_cocoa_touch.pdf)
> - What's New in Core Data on Mac OS X · Session 315
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/315/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_315__whats_new_in_core_data_on_mac_os_x.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_315__whats_new_in_core_data_on_mac_os_x.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/315_whats_new_in_coredata_on_macos.pdf)
> - What's New in Core Data on iOS · Session 303
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/303/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_303__whats_new_in_core_data_on_ios.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_303__whats_new_in_core_data_on_ios.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/303_whats_new_in_core_data_on_ios.pdf)
> - What's New in Core Location · Session 500
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/500/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_500__whats_new_in_core_location.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_500__whats_new_in_core_location.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/500_whats_new_in_core_location.pdf)
> - What's New in Core Motion · Session 423
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/423/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_423__whats_new_in_core_motion.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_423__whats_new_in_core_motion.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/423_whats_new_in_core_motion.pdf)
> - What's New in Instruments · Session 310
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/310/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_310__whats_new_in_instruments.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_310__whats_new_in_instruments.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/310_new_in_instruments.pdf)
> - What's New in OpenCL · Session 401
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/401/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_401__whats_new_in_opencl.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_401__whats_new_in_opencl.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/401_whats_new_in_opencl.pdf)
> - What's New in Safari Extensions · Session 514
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/514/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_514__whats_new_in_safari_extensions.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_514__whats_new_in_safari_extensions.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/514_whats_new_in_safari_extensions.pdf)
> - Working with Game Center · Session 409
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/409/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_409__working_with_game_center.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_409__working_with_game_center.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/409_working_with_game_center_v2.pdf)
> - Working with Media in AV Foundation · Session 415
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/415/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_415__working_with_media_in_av_foundation.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_415__working_with_media_in_av_foundation.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/415_working_with_media_in_av_foundation.pdf)
> - Working with iOS Accessories · Session 201
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/201/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_201__working_with_ios_accessories.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_201__working_with_ios_accessories.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/201_working_with_ios_accessories.pdf)
> - Writing Easy-To-Change Code: Your Second-Most Important Goal As A Developer · Session 112
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/112/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_112__writing_easytochange_code.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_112__writing_easytochange_code.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/112_wrirting_easytochangecode.pdf)
> - iAd Implementation Best Practices · Session 505
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/505/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_505__iad_implementation_best_practices.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_505__iad_implementation_best_practices.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/505__iad_implementation_best_practices.pdf)
> - iBooks: Create Beautiful Books with HTML5, CSS3 and EPUB · Session 507
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/507/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_507__ibooks.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_507__ibooks.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/507_ibooks.pdf)
> - iCloud Storage Overview · Session 501
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/501/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_501__icloud_storage_overview.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_501__icloud_storage_overview.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/501_icloud_storage.pdf)
> - iOS Accessibility · Session 122
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/122/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_122__ios_accessibility.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_122__ios_accessibility.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/122_ios_accessibility.pdf)
> - iOS Performance and Power Optimization with Instruments · Session 312
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/312/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_312__ios_performance_and_power_optimization_with_instruments.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_312__ios_performance_and_power_optimization_with_instruments.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/312ios_performance_and_power.pdf)
> - iOS Printing System · Session 108
>     [play](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/108/) |
>     [HD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_108__ios_printing_system.m4v) | [SD](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_108__ios_printing_system.m4v) | [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/108_ios_printing_system.pdf)

Comment: I just figured out that I can't complete my answer with subsequent years as StackOverflow has now stricter limits: "Body is limited to 38000 characters; you entered 114303."

Answer (score 4):

> and the videos from WWDC 2010 and WWDC 2011 are nowhere to be found

This seems not to be the case. For example:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/415/

That is a video from WWDC 2011 and it is found. One counterexample is sufficient to disprove the hypothesis...

Comment: Well, alrighty then.  Are they *all* there?

Comment: No idea. :) Every number I've tried works. I'll be glad to send you a list of session numbers known to me and you can have at it. — Also the situation for 2010 does seem more dire. Fortunately I have most of them.

Comment: I'm glad that you found this! So Apple has only unlisted them, and the videos may still be there if we figure out their address. I've just re-built such list in a separate answer.

Comment: As of Sept 2022, that video is no longer accessible.  Just redirects to a generic WWDC page.

Comment: @northernman Well you already know I have a copy.

Comment: Requires login but here is a 2011 working link https://download.developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_107__autosave_and_versions_in_mac_os_x_10.7_lion.m4v

Comment: @malhal I am logged in with my developer account but that URL gets an "unauthorized" page for me.

Comment: Requires Safari

Comment: @malhal That's what I use.

Comment: All 2011 videos except 2 for work for me: 133 shows forbidden in plain text and 203 the video plugin fails to load.